# Will KDE Plasma break Linux Mint XFCE 20.2?

Tags: linux-mint, kde, xfce, desktop-environment

Will installing the KDE plasma desktop environment on Linux Mint XFCE cause things to break? By that I mean will it cause things to be buggy/laggy?

I've heard that doing this on Cinnamon can cause problems for one reason or another, but I've heard nothing of how it reacts with MATE and XFCE, the latter being my current installation of Mint. In general I've heard that having multiple DEs is a horrible noob idea from some people while others say it is completely safe.

Answer (score 0):

Generally different Linux desktop environments share nothing aside from dependencing from some common libraries and using the same APIs to interact with the user. You can install as many DEs as you want. If you boot into any of them all others are basically dead files on your disk which do not interact with you or take any resources. DEs can have autorun entries in `/etc/xdg/autostart` or `$HOME/.config/autostart` but they are normally DE dependent, i.e. have this entry: `OnlyShowIn=XFCE;X-Cinnamon;` which instructs your current DE whether to load it on startup or not.

TLDR: there's no way it can possibly happen.

Comment: There are problems specifically in the Ubuntu world with this. Something about how the DEs are organized in meta packages. "Don't install multiple DEs" is indeed standard advice for Ubuntu distros, although I've never understood if that's valid or just cargo cult stuff.

Comment: I've installed all possible DEs on Fedora simultaneously - have never had any issues with that. If Ubuntu based distros are affected by this, this reeks of sloppy packaging.

Comment: I am not saying it is a bad idea in general, I have various DEs on my Arch at the moment and have done this on many different distros over the years. However, since the question is specifically about Mint, which is Ubuntu-based, experience on other distros isn't relevant and your TLDR might be mistaken. Whether or not that is "sloppy packaging" is also not relevant to the issue, no matter how true that may be.

Comment: If anyone has recent data with open valid bug reports to demonstrate any possible issues arising from having multiple DEs co-installed, I'll remove my answer.

Comment: @terdon I think what happens in such cases are (a) file associations and (b) theming (WM, GTK, icons) become a mess. And it becomes complicated enough that your average new user can't really fix it

Comment: This is interesting. Just within the Linux Mint world there doesn't seem to be a consensus on whether it is safe or "worth it". I've even come across an older post saying that mixing XFCE and KDE desktops is a TERRIBLE idea, because one uses GTK and the other QT.

Comment: Is there anything aside from ages old myths? Secondly, would be nice to see some technical explanations how e.g. XFCE and KDE couldn't mix considering they are using different toolkits.